# Cardboard app using three.js

Tags: cordova, three.js

Im creating cardboard app using three.js and cordova. I'm not able to render CSS3DRenderer twice in a page. Can any one help me out is there any way where i can create html content in three.js using cardboard effect.

Is it possible to add html content as a texture.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tough to say without code. Relatedly, have you seen http://www.sitepoint.com/bringing-vr-to-web-google-cardboard-three-js/

Comment: May be u'll find some informations with TOJI :
https://plus.google.com/+BrandonJonesToji/posts